# How to tag directory

Tags: linux, bash

I want to create directory for example `user/foldertemporary@tmp`. This tag tells me that this directory should be deleted after certain time, which I could find by this tag. Is there any command in Linux/Bash that can help me solve this problem?

Comment: Go for it. `foldertemporary@tmp` is a legal directory name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either add to the file's name as you have done with your '@tmp', or you can look at [Extended File Attributes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_file_attributes)

Here's an [example](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/linux-and-open-source/learn-to-use-extended-file-attributes-in-linux-to-boost-security/) of using them:

```
$ setfattr -n user.comment -v "this is a comment" testfile

$ getfattr testfile

# file: testfile

user.comment

$ getfattr -n user.comment testfile

# file: testfile

user.comment="this is a comment"
```